# CSS negative background image

Tags: html, css, joomla

May be somebody can explain me this CSS code.
I am currently watching Joomla template, where the background for navigation menu is a negative and non-existing background image....
Is it just some error or some CSS hack I have no clue about...
The code is:

```
#menuwrap {
background: url("/templates/images/backgrounds/-1") repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;

}
```

?! If I check with Firebug, it says: failed to load ; If I check the folder, there is not such file "-1"....Can I just change to something like:

```
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff
```

?

Comment: It can be a hack, but then again it can also be a small browser misinterpretation as it points to a non existent file '-1'. Does it work fine if you change it?

Comment: It works, the background I see is just White in color now;But - all my Statistics always show that visitors are visiting this file -1

Comment: If it works fine without it, it should probably be a browser misinterpretation or even a firebug bug :P.. Anyway, just in case, you should always rely on web standards and if that is a hack, there is no such standard.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there went something "wrong" in the script and the '-1' should say that there is no background image. So of course you can change or even delete the `background` property in favour to `background-color: #FFF;`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a hack, but then again it can also be a small browser misinterpretation as it points to a non existent file '-1'.

If you say it works fine without it, it should probably be a browser misinterpretation or even a firebug bug, don't worry :P... Anyway, just in case, **you should always rely on web standards** and if that is a hack, it is not based on any standard, so I suggest you corrected it with some well known CSS standards.

Answer (score 0):

the /template/images/background/-1 is your url to the background. The easiest way is to include the background-image in the folder of your index.html and replace that as your file name including the file extension. The error show up because may be your background file is not there or the name is not correct (file extension).